# Java Spring база PostgreSQL, как проверить проиндексировалось поле или нет?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring

Java Spring база PostgreSQL, как проверить проиндексировалось поле или нет?

Поставил аннотацию над объектом

```
@Table(
        name = "onliner_product",
        indexes = {
                @Index(name = "index_onliner_name ", columnList = "onliner_name")})
```

Пробую обращаться к элементам (элементов более 1 000 000) с запросом по полю onliner_name, с аннотацией и без, разницы в скорости работы не видно.

Как мне понять, что аннотация сработала?

Comment: посмотреть в том же pgAdmin или DBeaver, есть ли индексы (и какие) на интересующей таблице? Или надо именно программно?

Answer (score 0):

Тут хорошая статья https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-list-indexes/

Использовал эту команду

```
SELECT
    indexname,
    indexdef
FROM
    pg_indexes
WHERE
    tablename = 'table_name';
```